# Сортировка товаров по цене из категорий

Tags: mysql, sql

Проблема такая. Имеется список товаров.

[image: Вывод всех товаров]

По категориям товары хранятся уже в отсортированном порядке. Поле price DECIMAL.

Вопрос 1. Как вывести все товары, отсортированные по цене так, чтобы сортировка происходила только внутри каждой категории.

К примеру у category_id=1 выведется сперва товар с ценой 199, затем 299, 499 и 1200.

Вопрос 2. Можно ли в этом же запросе вывести количество категорий. То есть 3, если смотреть на данную картинку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*)
           FROM  test.products
           WHERE category_id = product.category_id)
FROM test.products product
ORDER BY category_id, price;
```

Comment: Запрос, что в скобках, возвращает для первых двух категорий 3, а для третьей 4.
Сработал вот этот запрос.
`SELECT *, (SELECT count(Distinct category_id)
FROM  test.products) FROM test.products product 
ORDER BY category_id, price;`

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос. Может дешевле/быстрее будет выполнить два запроса отдельно?

Comment: т.е. SELECT count(*)  FROM  test.products  WHERE category_id = 1 выдаст 3? Если да то смотрите данные в таблице

Comment: не должен :)
В целом нужный запрос я получил. Спасибо за наводку!